# Are both space & time complexity of this function O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Consider the following function:

```js
function logN() {
    if (n === 0) return;
    logN(n / 2);
}
```

Are both time complexity & space complexity O(log n)? 
The maximum depth of the recursion is O(1 + log n), by dropping constants we get O(log n).

Also if we consider that calling functions is one of the elements that causes time complexity, does it mean the Time Complexity too is O(log n)?

Comment: Yes, they are both O(log n) (each call requires O(1) for both memory and time, and there are O(log n) calls).

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity of your snippet is `O(log N)` since `N` is getting decreased every time by `2` and would take log<sub>2</sub>N steps to reach `0`.

Space complexity is although `O(log N)` too looking at the no. of recursive calls being made, however, modern compilers do adapt a [`tail call optimization`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) approach since your snippet doesn't do anything with the return value of the recursive call. So, there is no explicit need to maintain every single recursive stack frame apart from just the current one at hand.

So, technically speaking, we can say that the space complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: No, do not give such an advice. From the algorithmic point of view you can not say that compiler optimize (there is no compiler from that POV). Semantic of the operations must be respected. So, that algorithm is in O(log<sub>2</sub>(n) in time.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès You mean space? Time is surely O(log N). I presume we can't just see algorithms from just a pseudocode perspective all the time, the reality when run on some compiler matters too.

Comment: Yes space, sorry. *I presume we can't just see algorithms from just a pseudocode perspective all the time* alas that is the purpose of algorithmics. Your answer is good, but you can't says that *this* algo is O(1) space, only that we can eliminate recursion in this case to have another algo that computes the same thing in another manner and behavior and that compilers are able to transform algos. It may seems pedantic, but it is a matter of being precise.

Comment: If we take this one step further, an optimizing compiler may optimize this function out entirely (see e.g. [here on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EYqTj4axY)); it has no side effects, and it always terminates and returns nothing. Tail Call Optimization (TCO) is definitely worth mentioning; when analysing space complexity, I prefer TCO being *explicit* however - that is, not "praying to the compiler" that it optimizes this, but rather having a *hard guarantee* in the language reference that tail recursion does not use stackframes. In Lua for example `return f(...)` is *always* a tail call.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès side note: O(log2(n)) = O(log n); it's just a constant factor that we can omit.

Comment: @Luatic Absolutely. I wish to make it explicit too but I am unsure if all modern programming languages have this.

Comment: @nice_dev Python does not.

Comment: Kotlin will use TCO if you use the `tailrec` keyword.